# ASP.NET MVC relative path to JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to reference the jQuery library in my master page like so:

```
src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js")%>" type="text/javascript">
```

The source for the page shows:

```
<script src="/DocumentManagement/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which seems to be correct since my site's url is http://servername/documentmanagement.

However I am getting errors in the javascript functions indicating that the jQuery library is not found e.g. 'Object expected'.

The same code works fine on my dev(XP - ASP.Net dev server) machine but not on a Win2003 box (IIS). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for wasting your time!  The jquery reference was using the wrong version number!!! Brainfart!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the logs to see if the request is being made and what type of response it is getting?  The URL looks correct, so I'd suspect some configuration or permissions issue.

Comment: Yes.  That should tell you what requests are being made and what response they got from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could load up [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to get some help, and see if it's a problem on the client side. It will also help by getting any server responses (404, 403, etc.)